# How can I change TextView from another activity?

Tags: android

I want to change textview from another activity but that don't work

MainActivity (With textview)

```
public static TextView textViewObj;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main);

    textViewObj = (TextView) findViewById(id.textView10);
```

This is onClick in another activity:

```
public void onClick8 (View view) {
    //HERE IS ONCLICK MEHOD WHEN I CLICK TEXT CHANGE TO ANOTHER TEXT
    MainActivity.textViewObj.setText("Text change");
    //END
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(zem13.this, R.raw.dobre);
    mediaPlayer.start();

    }
```

**LOGCAT UPDATE**
When I run android studio that write this:
When I run android studio that write this:
When I run android studio that write this:

```
03-16 16:45:43.750    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-16 16:45:43.880    1703-1710/com.example.tom.kvz E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-16 16:45:43.880    1703-1710/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
03-16 16:45:43.890    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 65K, 5% free 3417K/3560K, paused 0ms, total 2ms
03-16 16:45:43.940    1703-1706/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 3823K/3968K, paused 49ms+1ms, total 51ms
03-16 16:45:43.980    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4229K/4372K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
03-16 16:45:44.000    1703-1706/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 4430K/4576K, paused 19ms+1ms, total 22ms
03-16 16:45:44.160    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 4432K/4576K, paused 47ms, total 47ms
03-16 16:45:44.160    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.560MB for 2266284-byte allocation
03-16 16:45:44.250    1703-1713/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6645K/6792K, paused 87ms, total 87ms
03-16 16:45:44.270    1703-1706/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 3% free 6645K/6792K, paused 17ms+0ms, total 20ms
03-16 16:45:44.580    1703-1706/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 36K, 2% free 7662K/7776K, paused 19ms+1ms, total 22ms
03-16 16:45:44.590    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
03-16 16:45:44.600    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
03-16 16:45:44.600    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz V/WebViewChromium﹕ Binding Chromium to the main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b1028e58}
03-16 16:45:44.650    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz I/chromium﹕ [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
03-16 16:45:44.650    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz I/BrowserProcessMain﹕ Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
03-16 16:45:45.460    1703-1756/com.example.tom.kvz W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
03-16 16:45:45.680    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb821be30, tid 1703
03-16 16:45:45.770    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
03-16 16:45:45.770    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz I/Ads﹕ Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB") to get test ads on this device.
03-16 16:45:45.790    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-16 16:45:45.790    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d11b20)
03-16 16:45:45.790    1703-1703/com.example.tom.kvz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tom.kvz, PID: 1703
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tom.kvz/com.example.tom.kvz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.tom.kvz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 16:45:45.850    1703-1735/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads952707653.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
03-16 16:45:45.960    1703-1735/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads952707653.jar' (success) ---
03-16 16:45:45.960    1703-1735/com.example.tom.kvz D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.tom.kvz/cache/ads952707653.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 116ms
```

Comment: what is happening when you run this code???

Comment: nothing happens it will remain the same :(

Comment: any errors while running???

Comment: @peter : Please read more about Android Application Fundamentals. In particular relating to Activities. *NEVER* declare any `public static` fields (variables) or methods and expect them to be accessible from other Android app components. If you want to pass data from one `Activity` to another then pass the data as an `Intent` extra in the `Intent` you use to start the other `Activity`. This is a *VERY* basic part of how Android works.

Comment: The text in the TextView isnt changing because when you call new Intent, MainActivity is called and the TextView is initialised once more. So instead of changing the text in the second activity, you just pass a bundle to MainActivity and retrieve the budle in  MainActivity and set it to the TextView..

Comment: @Squonk and lal can you help me with code?

Comment: I would need help with the code to change the TextView after onClick

Answer (score 0):

You can use **bundles** to send data from one activity to other.

To send bundle.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Name","Text Change"); //This is for a String
Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

to receive the bundle and set it to the `TextView` in the MainActivity

```
Bundle bundle = null;
bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String myString = bundle.getString("Name");//this is for String 
textViewObj.setText(myString );
```

**EDIT** - Thankyou @squonk for the suggestion

**OR**

Use this to send the string to MainActivity...

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);   
i.putExtra("Name", "Text Change");
```

To receive the string in MainActivity

```
extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String myString = extras.getString("Name");
textViewObj.setText(myString );
```

**UPDATE2**

First of all remove these 2 imports

```
import static com.example.tom.kvz.R.id;
import static com.example.tom.kvz.R.layout;
```

then, it should be

```
textViewObj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

So,This should be your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static TextView textViewObj;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);

        textViewObj = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        if(getIntent().getExtras().get("name") != null)
                textViewObj.setText((Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get("name"));

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onResume();
    }

        public void onClick17(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), kviz.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();



        }
    }
```

Comment: This is over-complicated. There is no need to create a `Bundle` and add it to the `Intent`. Simply using `i.putExtra("Name","Text Change");` will, by default, put a string extra into the `Bundle` the `Intent` already has. Similarly, you don't need to use `getExtras` to retrieve the `Bundle` in the other `Activity`. Simply calling `getIntent().getStringExtra(...)` is sufficient. Your approach is verbose.

Comment: @Squonk I have updated my answer..Thanks for the tip..I gave this answer because i thought it would be really helpfull for him in the future for passing more than one items to another activity..

Comment: Also comment out `AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` as you are getting nul from that..your logcat shows the errorcode as 0..

Comment: can you give me the whole MainActivity with imports?

Comment: How can i do that?? You just rewrite your previously written code with changes that i suggested in my answer.

Comment: Now what is the logcat??? Please post it..did you comment those lines that i mentioned in previous comment???

Comment: I do not understand you

Comment: I just asked you whether you commented out those lines which i told you in one of the previous comments in your code..also please post the new logcat..

Comment: where is the new logcat??

Comment: what is line no 30 in MainActivity.java?